# No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28: available for offline mode

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to build a new project in android studio but I keep on getting the error in the title it's saying I should disable offline mode but I already tried that to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem "No cached version listing for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+ available for offline mode." and the solution was by changing

```
"dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'"
```

in the gradle:app to

```
"dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'"
```

I wish this help somebody

Comment: Thanks for trying but I got it to work by changing the build tools version